# Couch base map reduce query

Tags: mapreduce, couchbase

I have a 3 Json Documents

Document 1

```
"No" : 1
"City" : "Patiala"
"Value" : 10
```

Document 2

```
"No" : 1
"City" : "Delhi"
"Value" : 11
```

Document 3

```
"No" : 1
"City" : "Patiala"
"Value" : 11
```

I want output like

```
 1    <Delhi or Patiala any one city>    32
```

I tried query with group level 2

```
map
function(doc, meta)
{
    emit(doc.No,[doc.Value,doc.City]);
}
```

reduce

```
function(key,values,rereduce){
    if(!rereduce){
        var sum=0;
        var s=[];
        var v=[];
        v=values[1];
        s=values[0];
        for(i=0;i<s.length;++i){
            sum+= s[i];
        }
        return (sum,v[0]);
    }else{
        var sum=0;
        var s=[];
        var v;
        v=values[1];
        s=values[0];
        for(i=0;i<s.length;++i){
            sum+= s[i];
        }
        return (sum,v);
    }   
}
```

and got the following error

```
(Reducer: Error building index for view `my_first_view`, reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null)
```

I only want to do group by on 'No' field but display any city.

Comment: You can change that using the group level attribute.

Comment: If group level is 1 it only displays city but if group level is 2 it combines cities and no. What I want is combine all the 'No' field and display any 1 city

Comment: Could you simply add the expected output to the question?

Comment: 1    <Delhi or Patiala any one city>    32

This is the output I want

Comment: In order to do that, you have to implement a custom reduce function that will merge data based on "No" but will keep some of the data..

Comment: I edited my post with the custom reduce function I made but getting the following error   (Reducer: Error building index for view `my_first_view`, reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CouchDB documentation generally warns against abusing reduce functions by doing this kind of thing, so it's probably worth testing out with datasets of a size you are expecting in production.

You are probably best off using a simple view with the map function you have and a reduce function sum on the `doc.Value`. Call this twice, once with query params `?reduce=false&key=1&limit=1` and once again with `?group=true&key=1`.

Having said all that, and this may kill your performance, this will do what you want in a single query.

Map Function:

```
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.No,[doc.City, doc.Value]);
}
```

Reduce Function:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
    var city;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
      if (!city){
        city = values[i][0];
      }
      sum = sum + values[i][1];
    }
    return [city, sum];
}
```

Query URL:

```
http://host:5984/db/_design/views/_view/view?group=true&key=1
```

Gives Result:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":1,"value":["Patiala",32]}
]}
```